# Is it possible to add a load more button that iterates through a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, load

Im using an api to get and display food recipes for a project.

```
function getrecipe(q) {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/search?apiKey=a568c4a88785422fbf4cf46b976c40e8&number=20&query=" + q,
      success: function (res) {
          for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
              document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<div class='pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3'><h1>" + res.results[i].title.substr(0,24) + "</h1><br><a href='" + res.results[i].sourceUrl + "'><img class='pure-img' src='" + res.baseUri + res.results[i].image + "' width='400' /></a><br>Ready in " + res.results[i].readyInMinutes + " minutes<br></div>"
              console.log(q);
          }
      }
  });
}
```

The html is

```
<input id="search-recipes" placeholder="Ingredient"><button class="pure-button" onclick="getrecipe(document.getElementById('search-recipes').value)">Search</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

The "number=20" in the url is how many recipes I'm getting back from the API. The for loop is displaying 4 results on my html page. How can I add a load more button that would iterate through and display the next 4 results?

Comment: Be careful not to put your apiKey in your question !

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy if you save the result in a global variable and then create a function to loop through it to display the result.

```
function getrecipe(q) {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/search?apiKey=a568c4a88785422fbf4cf46b976c40e8&number=20&query=" + q,
      success: function (res) {
          return res;
      }
  });
}
var resArray = getrecipe(q);
var x = 0;
var y = 4;
loadMore(); //this will run the function once

function loadMore(){
    for(var i=x ; i< y; i++){
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<div class='pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3'><h1>" + resArray.results[i].title.substr(0,24) + "</h1><br><a href='" + resArray.results[i].sourceUrl + "'><img class='pure-img' src='" + resArray.baseUri + resArray.results[i].image + "' width='400' /></a><br>Ready in " + resArray.results[i].readyInMinutes + " minutes<br></div>"
    }
    x = y;
    y = y+4;
}
```

HTML file

```
<input id="search-recipes" placeholder="Ingredient"><button class="pure-button" onclick="getrecipe(document.getElementById('search-recipes').value)">Search</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<button onClick="loadMore()">Loard More></button>
```